How to generate a unique target name in CMake?
For context, I've created a small function which calls add_custom_command to create a file, and I want this file to be generated as a dependency of my main project executable. In order to add the file as a dependency, I need to create a target that depends on the file with add_custom_target, and then I can add that target as a dependency to my main executable with add_dependency.
Obviously, the intermediate target name must be globally unique. But how can I generate a target name that is guaranteed (or very likely) to be globally unique? I tried using the full path name of the output file, but slashes are not allowed. And I cannot use only the file name, because that may not be unique across multiple invocations of the function.
function(my_function output_file ...)
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${output_file}
    ...
  )
  set(tmp_target what_to_name_the_target)
  add_custom_target(${tmp_target} DEPENDS ${output_file})
  add_dependencies(main_executable ${tmp_target})
endfunction(my_function)


add_custom_target(${output_file} ?  tried using the full path name of the output file, but slashes are not allowed sooo string(REPLACE ${output_file} output_file "/" "_")? You can also generate UUID or HASH.

@KamilCuk I already said in my question that using ${output_file} does not work due to it containing slashes.
